# Knowing the number of template parameters in the declaration

Tags: c++, templates

If I have,

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, int N>
class X {};
```

Is there any way, that I can know `class X` has 3 `template` arguments ?

**Use case in brief**: There are two library classes `ptr<T>` (for normal pointer) and `ptr_arr<T,N>` (for pointer to array). These two are interacting with another class in following way:

```
template<typename T>
void Clear(const T &obj)
{
  if(T::Args == 1) destroy(obj);
  else destroy_arr(obj);
}
```

So, I thought if we have some handy way of knowing the number of parameters, it would make it easy. However, I learn that I need to change my business logic as there cannot be such way.

Comment: reading the code? documentation? not sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: What's the real problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to query the number of template parameters of an arbitrary class?

Comment: @iammilind: do you mean that you want to obtain a compile-time integer constant equal to the number of template parameters of a specified template? If so, say so, since as you can see from Nim's comment "I know" is ambiguous. You do know that `X` in particular has three template paramters, because you wrote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this (unless you use variadic `sizeof(Args...)` in C++0x) but that's beside the point -- the question is wrong.

Use overload resolution.

```
template <typename T>
void clear (ptr<T> & obj) {
    destroy (obj);
}

template <typename T, int N>
void clear (ptr_arr<T,N> & obj) {
    destroy_arr (obj);
}
```

Comment: For that matter, you could probably overload `destroy` for `ptr_arr` too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `mpl::template_arity` (undocumented)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/mpl/aux_/template_arity.hpp

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Imagine the amount of overloads.

```
template<int> struct A;
template<bool> struct B;
template<char> struct C;
template<typename> struct D;
template<D<int>*> struct E;
template<D<bool>*> struct F;
template<typename, int> struct G;
// ...
```

For each of that, you would need a different template to accept them. You cannot even use C++0x's variadic templates, because template parameter packs only work on one parameter form and type (for example, `int...` only works for a parameter pack full of integers).

Comment: So what do you think of the use of mpl::template_arity?